# SELECT from wp_users, get Displayname too

Tags: users, user-meta, sql

```
SELECT   post_author, count(ID) as amount
FROM     dbold_posts
WHERE    WEEKOFYEAR( post_date ) = WEEKOFYEAR( NOW() )
    AND post_status = 'publish'
    AND post_type = 'post'
GROUP BY post_author
```

I can't figure out how I'll get the Display name, instead of "post_author" in this query.
It fetches the info as I want it - I just want the displayname instead of the authors ID.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is "the info that I want"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do a [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) on the users table in your old database, and also select the display name.

One key thing to note here, is that I aliased `dbold_posts` as `P`, and `dbold_users` as `U` - when dealing with multiple table, it's always best practice to specify which table you are referring to when mentioning a column.

```
SELECT   P.post_author, count(P.ID) as amount, U.display_name
FROM     dbold_posts P
JOIN     dbold_users U on U.ID=P.post_author 
WHERE    WEEKOFYEAR( P.post_date ) = WEEKOFYEAR( NOW() )
    AND P.post_status = 'publish'
    AND P.post_type = 'post'
GROUP BY P.post_author
```

Comment: I never learnt JOIN's. I'll give it a shot!

Comment: No problem! When dealing with data in 2 separate tables, Joins allow you to combine rows, essentially. Very useful :) Especically when dealing with the 3 term tables.

Comment: Yeah. I took a look at it, and it makes sense. U.ID=P.post_author. Thank you again!